# How DynamoDB keeps itself in sync with all regions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am creating one dynamoDB table using serverless.yml, this table will get created in multiple regions.

```
FreeTrailUsersDynamoDbTable:
  Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
  Properties:
    PointInTimeRecoverySpecification:
      PointInTimeRecoveryEnabled: true
    AttributeDefinitions:
      - AttributeName: id
        AttributeType: S
    KeySchema:
      - AttributeName: id
        KeyType: HASH
    BillingMode: PAY_PER_REQUEST
    TableName: ${self:custom.config.prefix}-free-trail-users
```

Now I want to know. How DynamoDB will keep upto date itself with different regions. Will creation on record in one region will get sync in other region.

Do I need to do extra thing from my side to these sync to happen ??

Comment: You're manually creating them in different regions or are you setting it to be a global table? In the former, nothing will be synced.

Comment: Yes, you would need to create a thing called "global table" which then uses DynamoDB streams to keep the regions in sync.